# Change button tooltip with style - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid loaded with a list of objects that have a property bool IsAutomaticSell. I need that when changing the value, the tooltip of the button of that row is updated. I have the following code but it does not work. Thx

**View.xaml**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Code"
                    Binding="{Binding Code}" />
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions"
                        Width="150">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AutomaticSellCommand,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Padding="10"
                        Margin="0,2,2,2">
                    <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="CurrencyDollar" />
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                               BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                    Value="DEFAULT_TOOLTIP" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAutomaticSell, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                             Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                            Value="NEW_TOOLTIP" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public ICommand AutomaticSellCommand => _automaticSellCommand ??
                         (_automaticSellCommand = new RelayCommand<OrderStatusDataWrapper>(AutomaticSell));

private static void AutomaticSell(OrderStatusDataWrapper orderStatusData)
{
    orderStatusData.IsAutomaticSell = !orderStatusData.IsAutomaticSell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind ToolTip.

XAML:

```
 <Button ToolTip={Binding ToolTip}" ... />
```

ViewModel:

```
public string ToolTip => (IsAutomaticSell) ? "DEFAULT_TOOLTIP" : "NEW_TOOLTIP";
```

Comment: Hi, I can not do that, the tooltip depends on the property of each datagrid row

Comment: @avechuche What is your `ItemsSource`? If you have a `ObservableCollection<T>` of items(rows) that each `T` has a `ToolTip` property, then what's the problem?

Comment: Yes is a ObservableCollection<T>, T contais a IsAutomaticSell property. The tooltip of each button in each row depends on that property

Comment: @avechuche Add another property named `Tooltip` to `T`, just like in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a ValueConverter in order to get this to work.

A ValueConverter will allow you to handle what to display based on your boolean value.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class BoolToContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public BoolToContentConverter()
    {
        TrueContent = "True Tool Tip";
        FalseContent = "False Tool Tip";
        NullContent = "No Value";
    }

    public object TrueContent { get; set; }
    public object FalseContent { get; set; }
    public object NullContent { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return NullContent;

        bool boolValue = true;
        bool isBool = true;

        try
        {
            boolValue = (bool) value;
        }
        catch
        {
            isBool = false;
        }

        if (!isBool)
            return NullContent;

        return boolValue ? TrueContent : FalseContent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your XAML you need to implement that converter.

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:l="clr-Example"
    ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <l:BoolToContentConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code"
                Binding="{Binding Code}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions"
                                    Width="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AutomaticSellCommand,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Padding="10"
                                    Margin="0,2,2,2">
                                <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="CurrencyDollar" />
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                                           BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}">
                                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                                Value="DEFAULT_TOOLTIP" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAutomaticSell, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                         Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                                        Value="{Binding IsAutomaticSell, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    ....
</Window>
```

Hope this answers your question. Cheers!

Comment: Hello, it does not work, when I click on the button and change the value of the property, the text does not change.

Comment: Hello,since I did not have the full source code, the code provided was an example of what you need to do in order to get this to work. If you are still struggling with this, let me know and I can help out.